# com.android.support:design:28.0.0 was producing error as Error inflating class TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

My App working fine in all devices in testing, where as from the deployment app some of the users greater than SDK 26 getting the error as

**Error inflating class TextInputLayout**

My build.gradle file was

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
```

**Layout file was**

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
   android:id="@+id/edt_username"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_boy"
   android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
   android:hint="@string/usernamehint"
   android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
   android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14sp"
   app:met_clearButton="true"
   app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
   app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
   app:passwordToggleTint="@color/grey">

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
         android:id="@+id/edt_password"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_locked"
         android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
         android:gravity="center|start"
         android:hint="@string/password"                                    
         android:inputType="textPassword|textNoSuggestions"
         android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I was unable to find the issue as it was working fine in testing.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Share your layout file as well.

Comment: added layout file

Comment: Try switching to bridge themes *(I.e. Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge)* for your **AppTheme**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest switching to androidX. Will probably fix your issue

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Comment: let me check and get back to you